# Which copy of a corrupt windows system file should I replace?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I have about 10  files in my C:\Windows\winsxs  folder that SFC reports are corrupt.

I'm replacing them from another windows 7 /64b machine.

But I see there are multiple copies of them.

I ran sfc /Scannow on the system I'm copying from and it reports all is fine.
Which copy on the destination machine should I update?
(Hoping it's now all of them b/c I have 10 files x 8 copies each=lots of work)

Here is a list of the files SFC could not repair:

```
2015-03-03 07:36:23, Info                  CSI    000001e1 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-03 07:36:24, Info                  CSI    000001e3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-03 07:36:36, Info                  CSI    000001ee [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\hpfstw73.dll" of prnhp005.inf, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-03 07:36:38, Info                  CSI    000001f0 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\hpfstw73.dll" of prnhp005.inf, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:05:10, Info                  CSI    000001e1 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:05:10, Info                  CSI    000001e3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:07:09, Info                  CSI    00000350 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:07:09, Info                  CSI    00000352 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:14:13, Info                  CSI    00000533 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:14:13, Info                  CSI    00000535 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:15:13, Info                  CSI    000006a2 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-03-05 12:15:13, Info                  CSI    000006a4 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"usb80236.sys" of netrndis.inf, Version = 6.1.7601.18076, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
```

Here are all the locations one file is in on the Dest PC.

[image]

Comment: You don't want to replace them from another computer.  You should only need to replace the component within the `WinSxS` directory since that's where the SFC tool looks.  You really don't want to do it manually.  You should be comparing your own files to a complete `WinSxS` directory that has the same patches installed as your system.  If you replace the wrong file wit the wrong version and reboot you will find you will be unable to boot into Windows.

Comment: I'd also add that if you are running into this many instances of corrupt files, you may want to consider re installing windows from scratch.

Comment: post the CBS.log so that we can see which files are corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If so many driver files are corrupted, you should repair Windows via an [Inplace Upgrade](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Boot Windows, insert the windows DVD or mount the ISO, run the setup.exe from the Windows DVD/ISO and select upgrade. This keeps all applications, files and repairs Windows.